# How to declare types for Cypress custom commands under typescript-eslint/no-namespace?

Tags: typescript, cypress, typescript-eslint

Cypress documentation shows how to declare [custom command types](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-custom-commands):

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      /**
       * Custom command to select DOM element by data-cy attribute.
       * @example cy.dataCy('greeting')
       */
      dataCy(value: string): Chainable<Element>
    }
  }
}
```

But Typescript ESLint is unhappy about this due to ["ES2015 module syntax is preferred over custom TypeScript modules and namespaces @typescript-eslint/no-namespace"](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-namespace.md). Is it possible to rewrite this to import/export and if so, how? Or should I just disable the rule for this case?

Comment: So, do you think the docs are wrong? What happened when you tried removing the namespace?

Comment: I think the docs don't take this rule into account because it isn't part of TypeScript. If I removed the `namespace Cypress` line, I expect it would declare a new `Chainable` interface unrelated to `Cypress.Chainable` and so I couldn't call the method on a `Cypress.Chainable` value; or do you mean something else? (I can't try it right now, but can later if you think it's useful.)

Comment: Are you trying with `allowDeclarations = true`, by default it's `false`. Also in a different way instead of putting this in global context , did you try creating a separate d.ts file with `declare module <> ` like syntax and then using directly in a .ts file:  `///<reference path="../typings/custom/your.d.ts" />`

Answer (score 10):

According to [this](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-namespace/), `@typescript-eslint/no-namespace` rule allows `declare` with custom TypeScript namespaces inside definition files.

So you may create a `cypress.d.ts` definition file and cut the types for your custom commands/assertions from the support file into this file:

```
// ./cypress.d.ts

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    /**
     * Custom command to select DOM element by data-cy attribute.
     * @example cy.dataCy('greeting')
     */
    dataCy(value: string): Chainable<Element>
  }
}
```

You might need to include the `*.d.ts` in the include options in any `tsconfig.json` files in your project for TypeScript to pick up the new types:

```json
// tsconfig.json

"include": [
  "src",
  "./cypress.d.ts"
]
```

check [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Using-an-External-Typings-File) for more info.