# Cypress 10: Custom command is not a function

Tags: typescript, cypress, angular-e2e, e2e

I have this error, cy. is not a function:

[image]

But I already updated the `e2e.ts` with this:

```
import './commands';
```

Here is my `commands.ts`:

```
    declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
    login(email: string, password: string): typeof login;
  }
}
//
function login(email: string, password: string): void {
  cy.visit('/login');
  cy.url().should('includes', 'login');
  cy.contains('Please sign in');
  cy.get('[name=email]').type(email);
  cy.get('[name=password]').type(password);
  cy.get('button').click();
}
//
// NOTE: You can use it like so:
Cypress.Commands.add('login', login);
```

What Am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `declare global {` around the type definition.

```js
declare global {
  declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
      login(email: string, password: string): typeof login;
    }
  }
}
```

See [Set Up TypeScript on Cypress in 4 Steps Easily](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/setup-typescript-in-cypress-in-4-steps-easily-78a6a8f60860) for a reasonably straight-forward discussion.

---

See also [How to declare types for Cypress custom commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73955190/16997707) for an alternative.